# Find set of $z \in \mathbb{C}$ when $z^4\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

To prove the question in my title.  Would my proof below be sufficient.  I saw a proof using demoivres formula but was wondering if my solution works.

**My attempt**

$$(a+ib)^4=a^4-6a^2b^2+b^4+i(4a^3b-4ab^3)$$

So we want $4a^3b=4ab^3$

Which implies that $a^2=b^2$ makes this true.

Comment: `implies that a^2=b^2` It actually implies that $ab(a^2-b^2)=0$.

Comment: You are missing a=0 b arbitrary and b=0 and a arbitrary solutions. Apart from that its good. You shd simplify a^2-b^2=0 to (a+b)(a-b)=0 so its clearer that it is 45 degree lines

Comment: Ok, that was a silly mistake on my part. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It means any member of $\mathbb C$ in the form $a+ia$ will  make the desired set . Also you can take $0$, $a$ and $ia$ forms.